# Observing the Redux store from descendent components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

import { initwidget, subscribeToPriceStream } from './widgetActions';

@connect(createSelector(
    (state, props) => state.widgets[props.widgetId],
    widget => ({widget})
))
@propTypes({ widgetId: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired })
export default class Tradingwidget extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(initwidget(this.props.widgetId));
        this.props.dispatch(subscribeToPriceStream(this.props.widget));
    }

    render() {
        const widget = this.props.widget || {};

        return (
            <div>
                {widget.title}
                // more goes here
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In `componentWillMount`, the first action will initialise the widget state with some default properties.  The second action will asynchronously subscribe to a service.  When I call the second action though, I need the state that was returned from the first action to be available so I can pass it through to the second action.

Given I'll want to trigger the `subscribeToPriceStream` action when certain state properties are changed, both when the widget is initialised via the `initwidget` action and from certain user actions, I figure I need to listen to state changes to do so.

What's the best way to do this?  I've seen that there is a `subscribe` method on the store, and also looked at [redux-rx](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-rx), which has an `observableFromStore` method, but if this is the recommended pattern, what's the best way to access the app store from descendent components?  Should I be passing the store via props all the way down the tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from asking elsewhere that whilst you can pass the store down via props through your tree, the better way is to use `this.context.store`, as [pointed out by the creator of Redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/issues/150#issuecomment-157603586) - it uses [React Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), so you need to specify `contextTypes` in your child component.

Personal preference perhaps, but I'd prefer to do this than pass it down through the tree.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your final question is yes, it's good practice to pass the store (or parts of it) down the component tree. Ideally you'd have very few top-level "smart" components that are aware of the store and use `connect`, and all the other components would only receive parts of the store via `props`. [Here's an explanation of the "smart" versus "dumb" components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

The idea to subscribe to store changes sounds right for this case. I've never done this myself yet, so I can't say what the caveats are. But yes, I agree that the call to `subscribeToPriceStream` shouldn't be here in the component. It should be treated as a separate action after `initwidget` has done its work and has moved the store to its new state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't end up going that way, but the last part of your second paragraph was useful anyway in thinking about how best to structure this.